# No exported member 'PreLoadAllModules', in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a demo app but got this error.I tried to solve it but can't.Please suggest me what I am doing wrong? I think the `PreloadAllModules` token from the Angular router package.

**The complete description of error is:**

**app/app-routing.module.ts(33,15): error TS2305: Module '"/home/angular2/test/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'PreLoadAllModules'.**

The code is given below:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes ,
         Router , ActivatedRoute,
         PreLoadAllModules         }    from '@angular/router'; 
import { NgModule                  }    from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent        }    from './dashboard.component';
import { TestComponent             }    from './test.component';
import { ContactComponent          }    from './component/contact.component';
import { DirectiveExampleComponent }    from './component/directive.exp.component';
import { PowerBoosterComponent     }    from './component/power-booster.component';
import { PageNotFound              }    from './component/page.not.found.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path:  'dashboard',                  component: DashboardComponent },
  { path:  'test',                       component: TestComponent },
  { path:  'contactus',                  component: ContactComponent },
  { path:  'directive',                  component: DirectiveExampleComponent },
  { path:  'pipeexamples',               component: PowerBoosterComponent,data:{name:'shubham',id:1} },
  { path:  '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path:  '**',                         component: PageNotFound},

];

@NgModule({
  imports:    [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{ preloadingStrategy:PreLoadAllModules }) ],
  exports:    [ RouterModule ],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@angular/router/src/router_preloader.ts` this class only exist in Angular 2.1.x or above, please make sure you using latest Angular version.

sources:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.x/modules/@angular/router/src/router_preloader.ts#L44-L48

Comment: I have updated my router_preloader.ts. But still having same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple mispelling I believe, the correct import is:

```
import { PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router/router';
```